# What authentication header to use in Asterisk?

Tags: java, sip, asterisk

i am currently developing a SIP client in pure java using the JAIN SIP API to reigster, authenticate and send messages to a Asterisk server running on a seperate machine.

I have approached the Registering and authentication process in two steps:
1. make a register SIP request
2. if response is 401(which it is) retrieve the WWW-AuthenticatonHeader from Asterisk and use the nonse to generate a md5 hash for the response field to be set on a AuthenticationHeader that i am populating.

The md5 will hash the username, password, request type etc and add it to a AuthenticationHeader.

After this, i then send the same request i made previously but with the AuthenticationHeader attached.

This is the example my code is based on:

http://vkslabs.com/sip-register-request-using-jain-sip/

The issue i am having is that the Asterisk server keeps responding with a 401 status code dispite adding the AuthHeaders with its md5 hashes of the username and password contained so i am wondering if Asterisk server uses a different kind of authentication challenge/method?

How can i access the Logs from Asterisks to see exactly why it rejects my Auth requests? Could it be bad username and password? invalid nonse?

At the moment the server just returns 401 without more information on exactly what is the issue.

Below is my code that creates that makes the register request and if failed, does it again but this time adding the AuthenticationHeader

```
public void registerClient(String username, String password,
            ResponseEvent evnt) throws Exception {

        cSeqHeader = headerFactory.createCSeqHeader(1, Request.REGISTER);
//      request = messageFactory.createRequest(requestURI, Request.REGISTER,
//              callIdHeader, cSeqHeader, fromHeader, toHeader, viaHeaders,
//              maxForwards);

        request = this.messageFactory.createRequest("REGISTER sip:"
                + toHost + " SIP/2.0\r\n\r\n");
        request.addHeader(callIdHeader);
        request.addHeader(cSeqHeader);
        request.addHeader(fromHeader);
        request.addHeader(toHeader);
        request.addHeader(maxForwards);
        request.addHeader(viaHeader);
        request.addHeader(contactHeader);

        request.addHeader(contactHeader);
        if (evnt != null) {
            request.addHeader(createAuthHeader(username, password, evnt, Request.REGISTER));
        }

        if (transaction == null) {
            transaction = sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(request);
        }

        transaction.sendRequest();
    }

    private AuthenticationHeader createAuthHeader(String username,
            String password, ResponseEvent response, String requestMethod)
            throws ParseException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        AuthenticationHeader header = (AuthenticationHeader) headerFactory
                .createAuthorizationHeader("Digest");

        // get authentication type and nounce from wwwAuthheader we receive from
        // response object
        WWWAuthenticateHeader wwwAuthHeader = (WWWAuthenticateHeader) response
                .getResponse().getHeader(WWWAuthenticateHeader.NAME);

        String nonce = wwwAuthHeader.getNonce();
        String qop = wwwAuthHeader.getQop();
        String realm = wwwAuthHeader.getRealm();
        String opaque = wwwAuthHeader.getOpaque();


        // prepare and md5 username password and realm.
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(wwwAuthHeader
                .getAlgorithm());
        ;
        String message = String.format("%1$s:%2$s:%3$s", username, realm,
                password);
        String ha1 = toHexString(messageDigest.digest(message.getBytes()));

        // prepare second md5 value for request method and request URI used
        String message2 = String.format("%1$s:%2$s", requestMethod, requestURI);
        String ha2 = toHexString(messageDigest.digest(message2.getBytes()));

        String responseValue;

        // check what type of digest we need and apply it auth header by
        // checking qop
        if (qop != null && qop.equals(AUTH)) {
            // Create the final MD5 string using ha1 + “:” + nonce + “:” +
            // nonceCount + “:” + cNonce + “:” + qop + “:” + ha2
            // responseValue = String.format("%1$s:%2$s:%3$s:%4$s:%5$s:",
            // ha1,nonce,)

        } else {
            // Create the final MD5 string using ha1 + “:” + nonce + “:” + ha2
            responseValue = String.format("%1$s:%2$s:%3$s", ha1, nonce, ha2);
            String responseConverted = toHexString(messageDigest.digest(responseValue
                    .getBytes()));
            System.out.println(responseConverted);
            System.out.println(wwwAuthHeader.getAlgorithm());
            System.out.println(username);
            System.out.println(nonce);
            System.out.println(realm);
            System.out.println(responseConverted);

            header.setAlgorithm(wwwAuthHeader.getAlgorithm());
            header.setUsername(username);
            header.setNonce(nonce);
            header.setRealm(realm);
            // header.setQop(qop);
            header.setURI(request.getRequestURI());
            header.setResponse(responseConverted);
            if(opaque != null) {
                header.setOpaque(opaque);
            }
        }

        return header;

    }

    private static final char[] toHex = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
            '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

    /**
     * From Nist/JAIN examples: convert an array of bytes to an hexadecimal
     * string
     * 
     * @return a string (length = 2 * b.length)
     * @param b
     *            bytes array to convert to a hexadecimal string
     */
    static String toHexString(byte b[]) {
        int pos = 0;
        char[] c = new char[b.length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            c[pos++] = toHex[(b[i] >> 4) & 0x0F];
            c[pos++] = toHex[b[i] & 0x0f];
        }
        return new String(c);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have use nonce sent in 401 request for your authentification. Please re-read sip RFC again.

Comment: Yes i have used nonse from first request. This is what i a.  Suppose to use according to the guide i am following. Is this wrong? Can you clarify please?

Comment: Also you can enabled debug on asterisk, it will say what exactly is wrong(i hope)

Comment: I dont understand you>? You said i used Nonse for my 401 request and i asked if you can clarify? pjsip is not written in java and the the JNI pjsip wrapper doesnt work and doesnt build/compile properly. the closest i have got to creating a sip client is by using JAIN SIP. The logs from Asterisk also doesnt tell me much information. All it states is some kind of miss match error. it does not state if my username password is wrong? md5 wrong? etc etc.